# How to access .net classes at design time view in ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net

Can you please tell me how to refer to .net classes at design time. For e.g I want to print the current datetime in a label or text box. I tried following code but my page is coming blank.

```
                        <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

                        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

                        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <head runat="server">
                            <title></title>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                            <div>
                            <label runat="server"><%# DateTime.Now.ToString() %></label>

                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="litDateNow" Text='<%# DateTime.Now.ToString() %>'></asp:TextBox> 

                            </div>
                            </form>
                        </body>
                        </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that you want to use .net classes, in any part of ASP.net page you can use **<%=  your classes %>** in top of any Asp.net page you can see a

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

so your **Page declerative** is using this pattern too

Answer (score 2):

That should be:

```
<label runat="server"><%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
```

You can use the above syntax

The syntax you have defined is used for databinding, not printing text

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display date from aspx page, write

```
<div>
    <%= DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()%>
</div>
```

No need to use any textbox or label control, if it is of no use in code-behind